# Reminder window in Ubuntu turns on full screen

Tags: fullscreen

Is it possible to make reminder windows smaller than full screen on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)?

[image]

I think that the name of the application is **Reminders**:

[image]

My resolution is 1920 x 1080 (16:9)

Comment: Please edit your question to include which software generates this reminder window, and what is your screen resolution.

Comment: I have the same issue. When a calendar reminder pops up, it blocks the entire screen until dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

The software is Calendar.
To turn it off, go to `Settings > Applications` and toggle the Notifications option.